# Parse file with non-standard layout into table

Tags: sql-server, json, ssis-2016

I have a file that I am getting from a vendor that I need to put into an SQL Server table. The data in the file looks like this:

```
{"result":"success","ReqCtx_requestURI":"somethinghere","eventDate":"2018-04-23","timeStamp":"2018-04-23T00:36:21.012-07:00"}  {"member":"123456789","ReqCtx_canonicalId":"03539","ReqCtx_userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

The format is "columnname":"value". My table has all the possible columns in it. What I am trying to do, if it is possible is to create sql insert statements based off of this info. Something like

```
insert into table(result,ReqCtx_requestURI,eventDate)
 values(success,somethinghere,2018-04-23)
insert into table(member,ReqCtx_canonicalId,ReqCtx_userId) 
values(123456789,03539,xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I could go about this?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, are you sure it looks exactly like that?

Comment: This is a small snippet, but yes it is formatted like that.

Comment: Well that string would have to be split using custom logic into separate JSON documents.

Comment: I kinda figured, I'm just not sure how I'd go about it.

Comment: Regarding this not being valid JSON, would valid JSON contain all columns from the table that is being used to populate each "row" including nulls? I am trying to figure out how to approach my vendor about this.

Comment: The spec is here http://json.org/ and it's very simple.  That string is two separate JSON documents separated by a space.

Comment: Thanks! I've addressed the issue with the vendor. Fortunately this is a pilot program they are developing so maybe I can get them to do things correctly.